# Install Brother MFC-7860DW in Kubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: printing

I just installed Kubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have a Brother printer, model MFC-7860DW, attached through the modem connected to my computer. When I attempt to install the printer via the OS, the OS "sees" the printer, but my model is NOT included in the list provided. Any help there?

I also downloaded the install package from Brother and attempted to use it. I ran the script, but I need to enter the device URI. How do I determine this (as well as the IP address)?

Thanks, Norm

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you're new to Ubuntu there are a few golden rules you have to use the first year you use Ubuntu:

- Only install applications from the software center (**This is the answer to your question**: *take the same series* Brother 7800 series or 7000 series)
- Before you buy anything, look for a Linux-Compatible logo.  If you cannot see a Linux Logo, look up the product name and "Linux" (forget about drivers: it's in the Kernel, or it's not)
- If you don't know: Google is your friend
- After you've read the first 15 entries of your Google search and nothing has come up, come here and search here.
- Still unclear?  Ask a question.  (your first one was not too bad). While asking a question, Ask Ubuntu is going to still search for questions that might be the same as yours.  If you've missed them, look into them first.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the MFC-7860DW broke my brain for too long with all the crazy suggested work arounds that accomplished nothing but make clutter.
My solution was installing the drivers off the Brother website as normal but used the model number MFC-7860DN instead.

Afterwards, print, scan, duplex all worked as expected... so far.